# Android drawables, 9 patch images

Tags: android, android-drawable, nine-patch

I have a file apple.9.png in my drawables folder and am trying to call this inside of my onDraw method.

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(getContext(), android.support.v4.R.drawable.apple);
```

in order to call `canvas.drawPicture()`

However, the word apple is red and it is telling me cannot resolve symbol 'apple'

Why cant it recognize the apple.9.png in the drawables folder?

I have also tried

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.support.v4.R.drawable.apple);
```

Answer (score 1):

> the word apple is red and it is telling me cannot resolve symbol
>   'apple'

This is because the image `apple` is not part of android support library and since you are specifying it to find image in support library, it gives `cannot resolve symbol`

To fix this use:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.apple);
```

This will refer to your `drawable` folder, and it will find image of apple.

For creating scaled Bitmap, refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777734/using-ninepatch-9-png-for-making-scaled-bitmaps)

Hope it helps!

Comment: how can I convert it into a picture?

Comment: by picture, do you mean a `Bitmap`?

Comment: Well I want to use canvas.drawPicture, or whatever other option I have